# How to add custom static methods to an existing c# struct?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and Vector struct.

I use Vector3.Distance(a, b) function a lot, but I've just noticed that I want a slightly modified version of it which ignores the Y component and gives the distance in horizontal space.
Lets call it a Vector3.HorizontalDistance(a, b).

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(position1, position2);
float horizontalDistance = Vector3.HorizontalDistance(position1, position2); //I want this
```

The horizontal distance method should look like this

```
public static float HorizontalDistance(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2)
{
    pos1.y = 0f;
    pos2.y = 0f;

    return Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2);
}
```

Right now I put this method in my Utils class and call it like this

```
float distance = Utils.HorizontalDistance(position1, position2);
```

But it doesn't feel right, it seems out of context without Vector3 name in in, I want to extend the Vector3's functionality and call it like this

```
Vector3.HorizontalDistance(a, b);
```

BUT I don't know how to do that, I couldn't find any information on this subject.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extension methods on a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656222/extension-methods-on-a-struct)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it's not what I wanted.

Comment: @harut9 why is this not what you wanted? For a type you didn't write (`UnityEngine.Vector3`) this is your only chance ... The answer to "Can I add a **static** method to an existing type?" I'd say the answer is simply "No, you can't!" ;)

Comment: `But it doesn't feel right, it seems out of context without Vector3 name in` .. how about calling your class `Vector3Utils` then? That would be the most obvious way I guess ..

Comment: Hi, totally agree with you, the best case would be to create a Vector3Utils class

Comment: I don't know if I should mark this question answered or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add code to the `Vector3` `struct`, but you can write an extension method. That's the best option for you to have clean code.

```
void Main()
{
    var p1 = new Vector3() { X = 2f, Y = 1f };
    var p2 = new Vector3() { X = 7f, Y = 3f };
    
    Console.WriteLine(p1.HorizontalDistance(p2));
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static float HorizontalDistance(this Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2)
    {
        pos1.Y = 0f;
        pos2.Y = 0f;

        return Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I already knew about extension methods, they don't seem clean and intuitive too, but thanks anyway, now I know that I can't add methods to Vector3 the way I wanted, but it's not a big problem

Comment: I'm curious what you might be thinking of (let's say you own the language spec) that might be more _clean and intuitive_ than an extension method

Comment: Extension methods would work on an instance though, OP is asking if it is possible to add a `static` method to the type itself to be called as `Vector3.XYZ` where I'd say the answer is simply "No, you can't!" ;)

Comment: @derHugo - Yes, I think I pretty much said that. I then went on to give the best alternative I could suggest.

Comment: @Enigmativity as OP says they know extensions but didn't want that ... I guess the best shot would be rather call their class `Vector3Utils` and call it a day ;)